# ClassNotFoundException in Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance() related to java applet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, applet

I created an `Applet` which connect to mysql database and insert rows in db. It is running file on localhost. But when I published the same on php web server, the mysql connect jar is not found. I am running the `Applet` from that server in the form of HTML file and I am getting exception of `ClassNotFoundException`. I have already put `mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar` in the same place where html and other class files exist. Also I created `web-inf/lib` on root and put the jar there but no luck. Below is the code.

```
Connection conn=null;
try {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://<ipaddress of domain>:3306/db_name";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "username"; 
    String password = "password";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("insert query");
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        showAlert("Error=" + e.getMessage() + ",ErrorCode="+e.getErrorCode() + "," + e.getSQLState());
    }
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    showAlert("InstantiationException=" + e.getMessage());
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    showAlert("IllegalAccessException=" + e.getMessage());
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    showAlert("ClassNotFoundException=" + e.getMessage());
}
```

Below is the HTML file code

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<APPLET CODE=app_test.class WIDTH=200 HEIGHT=100 archive='mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar'>
</APPLET>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: no need to specify newInstance() at driver load time and which IDE are you use for development

Comment: What is the HTML used for the applet when the HTML and Jar are in the same directory?  Who is this applet being served to?  (e.g. a company intranet, the internet to authorized users, the internet to all-comers..)

Comment: <HTML>
<BODY>
<APPLET CODE=app_test.class WIDTH=200 HEIGHT=100 archive='mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar'>
</APPLET>
</BODY>
</HTML>

Comment: Apart from the concrete problem, it's a *very bad idea* to do the JDBC inside an applet! See also this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323650/access-denied-when-using-jdbc-from-a-browser-applet

Comment: yeah, thanks for useful link for sharing.

Comment: OK - that HTML should work for loading the JDBC Jar from the same directory.  +1 to BalusC's warning.  That is what I meant to lead into by asking the 2nd question (which you have not answered yet).

Comment: the answer to 2nd quetion is that applet will be used by some group of logged in people using Internet. the site thru which they logged and applet where al reside exposed to Internet.

Answer (score -1):

Maneesh,
There are concepts called MVC that must be applied when developping web applications.

Applets should never access a database thus breaking the MVC paradigm.

Your applet should for the least, interact with a servlet which in turns speak to your controller (Database code).

Comment: since you're  right this is not and answer for the question, I have the same problem using `class.forname()` and your answer doesn't helps nothing.