# How to connect applet with database from browser

Tags: java, browser, jdbc, japplet

I'm looking for a way to connect my applet with DB from browser using glassFish Server. It's working when I run it with AppletViewer but when I tried to open it in the browser, it gave me an exception: no Suitable Driver Found.

This is my method:

```
public Connection getConnection(){
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

    try {
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","stage","stage");
        System.out.println("connect");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

    return conn;   
}
```

this is the HTML page

```html
<jsp:plugin 
  type="applet" 
  codebase="." 
  code="classes/MapApplet.class" 
  archive="applet.jar,ojdbc6.jar" 
  width="1350" height="747"> 
</jsp:plugin>
```

Comment: How and where do you deploy your applet?

Comment: I would suggest you to add this information (reasonably formatted) to your original question.

Comment: I edited the JSP.  Please [review the changes](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29324241/revisions) carefully.  BTW - 1) is the `MapApplet` class in a package named `classes`? 2) Are the Jars in the same directory as the (resolved location) HTML of the JSP?

Comment: @PM77-1  The OP posted a snippet of JSP after your prompting.  I suspect from the JSP that they are trying to access Jars/classes from the private directories (`classes` or `lib`) of a servlet container..

Comment: BTW - Change code of the form `} catch (Exception ex) { ..` to `} catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); ..`.

Comment: You really shouldn't use applets. After you solve this problem, you will probably be confronted with an "access denied" message, as an Applet cannot easily connect to an outside service like a database. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323650/access-denied-when-using-jdbc-from-a-browser-applet/7323712#7323712

Comment: so I need to use inputStreamReader o socket to make the connection between myApplet and DB   ?